# Weird word that I and my cousins used to say when young?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, abbreviations

When I was young, my cousins and I used to use the word: "Hon" (at least that's how I would write it) to get validation from another person that something occurred.

Example:

> Hon Alex that mom bought this game for us yesterday.

I think "Hon" is short for *honesty* or *to be honest*. Since I'm not from the United States and only went to visit them for summer vacations, I'm not sure where they got that expression from, a TV show or something like that. This happened in early 2000s, maybe 2004-2006.

Comment: Was it pronounced like the start of *honk*, or like the start of *hone*, or like the start of *honey*, or like the start of *honest*?

Comment: It was pronunced like the start of Honk, yes.

Comment: Could it have been *hunh* (which is pronounced without the /n/ but with a nasalized vowel, which might easily be the vowel in *honk*.

Comment: @PeterShor Wow, I think this would be the right answer,  as said in this website: https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/hunh/
"Hunh is an interjection that conveys annoyance, confusion, or curiosity. It also adds emphasis at the end of the question." it goes along with the context I provided, so, I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it have been *hunh* (which is pronounced without the /n/ but with a nasalized vowel, and which might easily contain the vowel in *honk,* although I believe that it more often contains the vowel of *hunk*).

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/hunh/) defines *hunh* as

> an interjection that conveys annoyance, confusion, or curiosity.

Comment: Huh Alex that mom bought this game for us yesterday. ??

Answer (score 1):

Since the meaning you remember was *honestly,*"hon" may have been short for

> **honest Injun**
>
> *Dated, offensive US*
>
> Honestly; really.
>
> *I won't run away, honest Injun* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/honest_injun)

> ORIGIN OF **HONEST INJUN** 1870–75, Americanism; see Injun
>
> USAGE NOTE FOR HONEST INJUN Honest Injun uses an informal, nonstandard
> spelling of Indian. Probably first used by Mark Twain, this expression
> is now dated and often perceived as insulting to or by American
> Indians. Though it came to mean “honestly or truly,” it may have had
> its origin in the contrary perception that Indians on the American
> frontier were not considered honest or trustworthy until they had
> proven themselves, for example, as scouts. See also Indian.
> [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/honest-injun)

Although I remember it from my childhood, I would have thought this expression was out-of-date by the early 2000's, but perhaps not, given the date of the *Scouting* magazine admonition.

---

> "Tom—**honest injun**, now—is it fun or earnest?"  [Mark Twain; *The Adventures of Tom Sawyer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Adventures_of_Huckleberry_Finn/x1z-TvdRSKMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Honest%20Injun%22&pg=PA224&printsec=frontcover) (1876)

> "Do yer ask **honest Injun,** no cheatin' nor nothin?"
> "Certainly.
> Perfectly '**honest Injun**.'" [Blanche Willard Howard; *One Summer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/One_Summer/Zrg-AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22honest%20injun%22&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover)
> (**1875**)

> Don't use derogatory words and phrases, such as "Injun," "**honest
> Injun**," "Indian giver," "too many chiefs and not enough Indians," "as
> wild as a bunch of Indians," "squaw," "half-breed," or "papoose."
> [*Scouting*, Vol. 85, n.6](https://books.google.com/books?id=dP0DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22honest%20injun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO9-KMqf30AhWBl2oFHf4yALEQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22honest%20injun%22&f=false) (1997)

Comment: But *honest* is pronounced on-est, so where is the *h* sound as in the OP's description?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I'm not sure. Perhaps in strenuous play it got "breathy" (?) But we're looking for a word kids would use to mean *honest(ly)*, and I don't think there are many. I'm thinking the OP's memory of the meaning may be clearer than the recollection of the sound.

Comment: I was thinking *Scout's honor*, but abandoned that due to no *h* sound.